# ImportError: No module named paths ipython notebook and bokeh using enthought in windows

Tags: python, ipython, enthought, bokeh, jupyter-notebook

I'm receiving the following error  trying to run a plot with bokeh in an Ipython notebook

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-128-bedfa82edaf4> in <module>()
  9 p.line(logged_ts.index, logged_ts[[1]], color='navy', alpha=0.5)
 10 
---> 11 show(p)

C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\bokeh\io.pyc in show(obj, browser, new)
299 
300     '''
--> 301     return _show_with_state(obj, _state, browser, new)
302 
303 def _show_with_state(obj, state, browser, new):

C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\bokeh\io.pyc in _show_with_state(obj, state, browser, new)
307 
308     if state.notebook:
--> 309         comms_handle = _show_notebook_with_state(obj, state)
310 
311     elif state.server_enabled:

C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\bokeh\io.pyc in _show_notebook_with_state(obj, state)
329         comms_target = make_id()
330         publish_display_data({'text/html': notebook_div(obj, comms_target)})
--> 331         handle = _CommsHandle(get_comms(comms_target), state.document, state.document.to_json())
332         state.last_comms_handle = handle
333         return handle

C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\bokeh\util\notebook.pyc in get_comms(target_name)
109 
110     '''
--> 111     from ipykernel.comm import Comm
112     return Comm(target_name=target_name, data={})
113 

C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\__init__.py in <module>()
  1 from ._version import version_info, __version__, kernel_protocol_version_info, kernel_protocol_version
 ----> 2 from .connect import *

 C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\connect.py in <module>()
 12 
 13 from IPython.core.profiledir import ProfileDir
---> 14 from IPython.paths import get_ipython_dir
 15 from ipython_genutils.path import filefind
16 from ipython_genutils.py3compat import str_to_bytes

ImportError: No module named paths
```

I've already tried uninstalling the ipython package using pip and package manager without result.
Any help would be appreciated, regards!

Comment: `from IPython.paths import get_ipython_dir` succeeds on my installation of Canopy 1.7.2 on Windows 7. Do you have any other Python installations referenced in your environment? You can check by running `set | sort` at a Windows Command Prompt.

Comment: Not that I remember. this is the output I get running the command  http://txt.do/5b27q

Comment: What version of the notebook? Perhaps your notebook version is too old?

Comment: My version is 1.5.2

Answer (score 1):

When you use `pip` with a package that was already installed with Package Manager (including packages that are bundled with Canopy), you will likely end up with an incompatible mix of files. I suggest that you uninstall Canopy 1.5.2 and install the current version, 1.7.2. Before restarting Canopy, be sure to delete the other directories that Canopy creates. See https://support.enthought.com/entries/23580651-Uninstalling-and-resetting-Canopy

In particular (and whether or not you update to Canopy 1.7.2), you will need to delete this directory before restarting Canopy: `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\`

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary to uninstall and reinstall canopy? I fear that means uninstalling packages that I struggled a lot to make them work in windows. Is there a chance that if I only restart canopy and delete this suggested directory to fix the path problem?

Comment: It's actually the opposite. Uninstalling and reinstalling Canopy will have no impact on your set of installed packages. Deleting that directory will remove all those packages. So since you do want to preserve your manually-installed packages, I suggest that instead of deleting it, you try `enpkg --forceall ipython`